# C# HTTP Post request from a chatbot in MS Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am a very novice C# person so please dont be too hard on me

Im trying to make a post request to MSFLOW from a MSBOT Framwork chatbot. The post request triggers the flow to send an email to chatbot users manager.

I just dont know where to start. I have a basic BOT template from Az but how and where should I put the request

Many thanks

Comment: You basically want to call a web api from within your bot code ?

Answer (score 0):

use [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class)

here is an example of using Http **POST** request .

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestPostExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/post");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the Flow needs an **Request - When an HTTP request is received** trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres  The trigger can be fired by calling it with any rest client: https://flow.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/call-flow-restapi/

Most likely, the bot will make the call to the HTTP Request Trigger when the bot is messaged something specific by a user.  Notice the **BasicBot.cs** file has an **OnTurnAsync** method.  Within here, you can check the .Text property of the activity and if it is "send email" then call the Flow Trigger:

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
{
    if(active.Text == "send email")
    {
       await SendEmail();
    }
    else
    {
        //  other BasicBot.cs code
    }
...
```

As demonstrated by M.zK, you can use **WebRequest** in C# to make the Flow Trigger call.  You can also use HttpClient:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://prod-13.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/etc"))
{
    var content = new { Properties = new { Property1 = "property 1 value", Property2 = "Property 2 value" } };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
    request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```